# How do i disable selected value from a dropdownlist in another dropdwnlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have 2 dropdownlist. If I select a value from one first dropdownlist those value shouldn't be seen in the second dropdownlist. How to do that in MVC?
Here's the part in cshtml:

[image]

For example, here once I select IT in the first select, it should be excluded in the second drop down.

```
<select class="chosen-select subjects" multiple id="subjects" asp-for="@Model.Subjects[j].SubjectIds" required>
</select>
```

Comment: Please include your markup, without it can be hard to give you a good answer, and also you should provide all relevant information.

Comment: If the dropdown IDs share the same value, you could simply have an `onChange` on the first and in jQuery/ js disable the value/ remove the value from the second dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onChange` attribute .Remove in the second dropdown when you select in the first dropdown.

**[Note]** I use asp-items to bind data in dropdown.

View:

```
@model SelectRemove.Models.EmployeeViewModel  

           <select id="select1" onchange="getSelectValue(this.value)" class="form-control" name="EmployeeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList, "Value", "Text"))">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>  
           </select>  
                                               
            <select id="select2" class="form-control"name="EmployeeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList, "Value", "Text"))">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>  
            </select>  
               
                 
         
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function getSelectValue(select1)
        {
            if(select1!='')
            {
                $("#select2 Option[value='"+select1+"']").hide();
                 $("#select2 Option[value!='"+select1+"']").show();
            }
        }
    </script>

}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:** If use chosen-select, you can try the bellow code.Sorry for my late reply.

View:

```
@model SelectRemove.Models.EmployeeViewModel  
           <select id="select" class="chosen-select" multiple="multiple"   style="width:100%;" name="EmployeeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList, "Value", "Text"))">
                   
           </select>   
                                               
            <select id="select" class="chosen-select"  multiple="multiple" style="width:100%;" name="EmployeeId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.EmployeesList, "Value", "Text"))">
                  
            </select>   
@section Scripts{
            
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         function activateChosen($container, param) {
            param = param || {};
            $container.find('.chosen-select:visible').chosen(param);
            $container.find('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            activateChosen($('body'));

             $(".chosen-select").change(function (e) {
                // Show all select 
                $('.chosen-select option').each(function () {
                    $('.chosen-select option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').attr('disabled', false).trigger("chosen:updated");                  
                    //$select.trigger('chosen:updated');
                });
                // Hide selected option excep none
                $('.chosen-select option:selected').each(function () {
                    $('.chosen-select option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').not(this).attr('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");  
                }); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What if I'm trying to do using chosen-select?

Comment: I update my answer.Sorry for my late reply.